# Strange css priority behavior for font-family in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-family

I need to customize styles for my menu. In IE, it works fine, but in Chrome, I find I cannot modify the font-family for links in the menu. For text in span or div, it's OK. I use simple selector to make my rule prior to default rule. But the development tool shows like this:
[image]

You can see that my rule doesn't override the default rule. I tried to add important, development tool shows OK as below, but the font doesn't change at all:
[image]

The only thing I tried to make my rule work is to delete the original CSS rule ".tundra .dijitMenuItem" in "Menu.css". But it is the default rule given by framework, I don't want to modify it.

The element in dom is shown below:
[image]

How can this happen, and how to make my rule work?

**Updated**: I tried many ways to test the behaviors. Seems like if only I put my rule to .dijitMenuItem or it's children, it can override the default. Otherwise, no matter how specific my selector is, it won't be applied. I made a simple example like below: the complete example is on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKyLG/4/):

```
.theme .sub-container
{
  font-family: Arial; 
}

body.theme div.container
{
    font-family: sans-serif; //this doesn't work
}



.theme .sub-container2
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body.theme div.sub-container2
{
    font-family: Arial; //this works
}
```

Can anyone explain this? Does font-family's inherit and overridden are different with other CSS properties?

Comment: What is the HTML for the element that is affected?

Comment: @Juhana, the HTML is updated in the question. It is a anchor in a popup div

Comment: But it doesn't have any of the classes specified in the rules?

Comment: @Juhana, Yes, because I need all text no matter anchors or spans or div use same font-family in the popup. Do I have to set it specific for anchors?

Comment: The example doesn't work only because you misspelled "sans-serif".

Comment: @Juhana, thanks to point it out. I correct the spelling and it results the same.

Comment: Well, now it's because Arial is usually the default sans-serif font -- you can't see the difference between "sans-serif" and "Arial". See http://jsfiddle.net/pKyLG/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Set the font family in your anchor tag. i think it should be work.

Comment: Yes it works. But I wonder why ".tundra .dijitMenuItem" can be prior to ".tundra .dijitMenuPopup .menu-popup"

Comment: if u want all fonts are same ,set the font family in body.

Comment: if my answer is helpful for u pls accept

Comment: But as I said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229865/strange-css-priority-behavior-for-font-family-in-chrome/14230283#comment-19740709, I need to apply it to all items in popup div. So I can not set it only for anchor. And put the rule to body or the container div both doesn't work.